# CONVERT varchar to decimal not working on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

1st of all I am working on SQL Server 2012 Express 64-bit.

I am trying to convert a varchar field to decimal and multiply to another varchar too.

This is the code I am trying to run on a SELECT query:

```
(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0.00))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM2, 0.00)))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'
```

Where PARAM1 and PARAM2 are varchar.
The numbers on this fields are 1 and 2. So simple. I want it to return 3.00 but the shown error is:

> Mens. 8114, Nivel 16, Estado 5, Línea 1
>   Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric.

I just want to get the result of PARAM1 * PARAM2 even if PARAM1 or PARAM2 are null (being converted to 0) or if they're decimal (separated with dot, for example: 100.5)

I don't get why it isn't working... Thanks!

FOUND THE ERROR:

COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0.00) makes it fail "converting varchar to numeric"; and COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0) makes it fail "converting varchar '100.5' to int." (which is not my intention anyway)

How could I make this "work"?

SOLUTION BY JATIN:

SELECT (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), NULLIF(REPLACE(Lineas.PARAM1,' ',''),'')), 0.00)) * (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), NULLIF(REPLACE(Lineas.PARAM2,' ',''),'')), 0.00)) AS 'MULTIPARAM'

what i did is first REPLACE all spaces and then if it is empty string then set it to NULL, rest is the same

Comment: Please translate to English

Comment: select (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(1, 0.00))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(2, 0.00)))  AS 'MULTIPARAM' returns 2.0000

Comment: MusicLovingIndianGirl: spanish is not japanese or russian, it is logically readable "error convert varchar to numeric".
BIDeveloper: Thanks but not working, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), Lineas.PARAM1), 0.00)) * (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), Lineas.PARAM2), 0.00))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'
```

the issue is here..

```
SELECT COALESCE('1', 0.00)
```

if still you get error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric", then your data has some characters else than 0-9.

Comment: Not working, same error. The only way it works is without decimals. I need with decimals

Comment: there must be some non numeric characters in your columns PARAM1 or PARAM2. Please do a direct query to check if so. Try this SELECT CONVERT(decimal(12,2), Lineas.PARAM1) and same for PARAM2

Comment: just tried but still not working if any of these has a decimal dot

Comment: that is strange! check this, its working :  DECLARE 
 @PARAM1 VARCHAR(2) = '111.222'
 ,@PARAM2 VARCHAR(2) = '222.111'
SELECT (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), @PARAM1), 0.00)) * (COALESCE(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), @PARAM2), 0.00))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'

Comment: yup, it is :S i know it's strange

Comment: If the query works with variable than surely there is something odd with the data, other than the decimal dot... might be a space with number

Comment: I found that when I only select the numeric data (100.5 and 50) it works, but the other files with null values it what makes it fail, even with the coalesce

Comment: FOUND THE ERROR:

COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0.00) makes it fail "converting varchar to numeric"; and COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0) makes it fail "converting varchar '100.5' to int." (which is not my intention anyway)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115167/discussion-between-jatin-patel-and-jinfo).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to kick yourself.

Error message in English;

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 12
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

Sample Data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, Field1 varchar(10), Field2 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
(1,1,1)
,(2,1,2)
,(3,1,3)
,(4,1,4)
,(5,2,1)
,(6,2,2)
,(7,2,3)
```

Query (remove the decimal places from your coalesce);

```
SELECT 
ID
,Field1
,Field2
,(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(a.Field1, 0))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(a.Field2, 0)))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'
FROM #TestData a
```

Result;

```
ID  Field1  Field2  MULTIPARAM
1   1       1       1.0000
2   1       2       2.0000
3   1       3       3.0000
4   1       4       4.0000
5   2       1       2.0000
6   2       2       4.0000
7   2       3       6.0000
```

If you want the result to two decimals then use this;

```
SELECT 
ID
,Field1
,Field2
,CONVERT(decimal(12,2),(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(a.Field1, 0))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(a.Field2, 0))))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'
FROM #TestData a
```

Which gives these results;

```
ID  Field1  Field2  MULTIPARAM
1   1       1       1.00
2   1       2       2.00
3   1       3       3.00
4   1       4       4.00
5   2       1       2.00
6   2       2       4.00
7   2       3       6.00
```

If you have decimals in the varchar field, then give this a go;

```
CONVERT(decimal(12,2),COALESCE(CAST(a.Field1 AS decimal(12,2)), 0) * COALESCE(CAST(a.Field2 AS decimal(12,0)), 0))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the two ways but still not working:


(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(PARAM1, 0))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(PARAM2, 0))))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'


(CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0))) * (CONVERT(decimal(12,2), COALESCE(LINEAS.PARAM2, 0)))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'

This two queries gave me the same error:
Mens. 245, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar '100.5' al tipo de datos int.
In english means that the conversions are not to decimal, are to int; but we are using "decimal"...

Comment: could you run ISNUMERIC(Field1) on both fields to ensure that you definitely do have data that is convertible to an int? It should return a 1 for all rows, if you get any zeroes then you've got some broken data. Both of the queries you posted work for me on the test data provided

Comment: they both return 1 but with coalesce   ISNUMERIC(COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0))  I got the mistake of int

Comment: Try CONVERT(decimal(12,2),COALESCE(CAST(a.Field1 AS decimal(12,2)), 0) * COALESCE(CAST(a.Field2 AS decimal(12,0)), 0))  AS 'MULTIPARAM'

Comment: Msg. 8114, Level 16, Status 5, Line 1
Error converting from varchar to numeric

Comment: Ok, update your question with the create table script for the table you're using, also post some sample data (the data that's causing you issues)

Comment: sorry but i haven't permission to that (I work on "closed-box" without permissions). The data is all null except two files that I manually change for the tests. With integers works, but with decimals not.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. You're going to have to find out what data you have an issue with and fix it. Without more information there isn't anything more I can do.

Comment: thanks anyway, if I find the mistake i'll update this

Comment: I found that when I only select the numeric data (100.5 and 50) it works, but the other files with null values it what makes it fail, even with the coalesce

Comment: FOUND THE ERROR:

COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0.00) makes it fail "converting varchar to numeric"; and COALESCE(Lineas.PARAM1, 0) makes it fail "converting varchar '100.5' to int." (which is not my intention anyway)